# Event subscription on async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, event-handling

I wanna launch the `LoadDataAsync` in 2 ways. First by an event with the subcription in `FormLoad()` and by a classic method `ManualLoad()`.

But I can't make it work.

I can't make subscription on task return. With `void` it's works, but with `void` can't `await` in the `ManualLoad()` method. How make both ways work?

```
    public delegate void ProductDelegate(long? iShopProductId);
    public event ProductDelegate ProductSelectionChanged = delegate { };

    public async Task LoadDataAsync(long? iProductId)
    {
        //await action....
    }

    //first way
    public void FormLoad()
    {
        this.ProductSelectionChanged += LoadDataAsync //UNDERLINED ERROR;
    }

    //second way
    public async Task ManualLoad()
    {
        await LoadDataAsync(2);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous events in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761852/asynchronous-events-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As events do not support `async Task` you neeed to work around that via "wrapping" it, e.g.:

```
this.ProductSelectionChanged += async (s, e) => await LoadDataAsync();
```

Here I created an anonymous method/handler with a signature of `async void` which does nothing else then `await` the task-returning `LoadDataAsync`-method (may you should add `ConfigureAwait(false)`, depending on your specific use case).

Comment: thanks a lot. Just to be perfect for my sample the answer is this.ProductSelectionChanged += async (s) => await LoadDataAsync(s);

Comment: warning: subscribing via anonymous delegate may potentially introduce bugs when you try to unsubscribe it and re-subscribe it, see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803064/event-unsubscription-via-anonymous-delegate