# Passing arguments to an event handler

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, handler

In the below code, I am defining an event handler and would like to access the age and name variable from that without declaring the name and age globally. Is there a way I can say `e.age` and `e.name`?

```
void Test(string name, string age)
{
    Process myProcess = new Process(); 
    myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
}

private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  //  I want to access username and age here. ////////////////
    eventHandled = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Process exited");
}
```

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644253/c-sharp-pass-parameter-to-eventhandler

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# passing extra parameters to an event handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215845/c-sharp-passing-extra-parameters-to-an-event-handler)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes, you could define the event handler as a lambda expression:

```
void Test(string name, string age)
{
  Process myProcess = new Process(); 
  myProcess.Exited += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
      // name and age are accessible here!!
      eventHandled = true;
      Console.WriteLine("Process exited");
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect solution. This is clean and powerfull. Thanks

Comment: Really, very elegant solution!

Comment: What happens if you call Test(...) again before myProcess has exited? Does the lambda create a hidden class that hold the arguments from the Test(...) function?

Comment: This lambda method makes reuse impossible. If you have several senders that should act the same, a function after the += is much clearer and maintainable then using the lambda expression. Suppose you 10 buttons, which should all do the same when pressed, with only one small exception, depending on the sender, then using the lambda expression requires you to write the lambda expression after the += for every button clicked event. Are you sure they will remain the same after code changes?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to access username and age, you should create handler which uses custom EventArgs (inherited from EventArgs class), like following:

```
public class ProcessEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public string Name { get; internal set; }
  public int  Age { get; internal set; }
  public ProcessEventArgs(string Name, int Age)
  {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Age = Age;
  }
}
```

and the delegate

```
public delegate void ProcessHandler (object sender,  ProcessEventArgs data);
```

Comment: He's using the Exited event of Process which when triggered will never be able to pass ProcessEventArgs to your handler