# Use XsltMessageEncounteredEventHandler to Populate String C#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I would like to populate a logging object I have when I use the "xsl:message" function inside of an XSLT and transform an XML object. Here's the code that I have:

```
string xmlValidationMessage;
XsltArgumentList argList = new XsltArgumentList();
argList.XsltMessageEncountered += new XsltMessageEncounteredEventHandler((sender, e) => MessageCallBack(sender, e, ref xmlValidationMessage));

using (XmlReader oldDocumentReader = convertedPayload.CreateReader())
{
    using (XmlWriter newDocumentWriter = reconstructedPayload.CreateWriter())
    {
        transformer.Transform(oldDocumentReader, argList, newDocumentWriter);
    }
}

private void MessageCallBack(object sender, XsltMessageEncounteredEventArgs e, ref string validationMessage)
{
    validationMessage += $"In XSLT: {e.Message}\r\n";
}
```

The purpose of this is to log XSLT messages to a logging object I have outside of the code. But I noticed posts talking about how refs and outs can't be used inside delegate methods, too. Does anyone want to offer an alternate suggestion, or some way to do this so that I populate a logging string with these XSLT messages rather than just logging to the console?

I was writing this code based on the article I found here, and some other Stack Overflow posts:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xsltmessageencounteredeventargs?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN

[Passing arguments to an event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293471/passing-arguments-to-an-event-handler)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider to use a `StringBuilder` as a property or field

```
StringBuilder validationMessages = new StringBuilder();

private void MessageCallBack(object sender, XsltMessageEncounteredEventArgs e)
{
    validationMessages.Append($"In XSLT: {e.Message}\r\n");
}
```

and where you need all messages you use `validationMessages.ToString()`.