# How to insert a 2 second interval after the tone is played?

Tags: c#, timer

```
System.Timers.Timer intervalTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000); // set the timer for 2 sec.
intervalTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(intervalTimer_Elapsed);

private void doHearingTest(ArrayList TestSeq)
    {
        if (!initialTestCompleted && testPerFreqLeft == totalTestPerFreqForInit)
        {
            label1.Text += testFreqSet[(int)initTestSeq[currentFreqIndex]] + " , ";
            if (currentFreqIndex == numOfFreqTested - 1)
                label1.Text += " || ";
        }
        else if (initialTestCompleted && testPerFreqLeft == totalTestPerFreqForMalig)
        {
            label3.Text += testFreqSet[(int)maligTestSeq[currentFreqIndex]] + " , ";
            if (currentFreqIndex == numOfFreqTested - 1)
                label3.Text += " || ";
        }
        #endregion

        leftRightPan = (currentFreqIndex < numOfFreqTested) ? 10000 : -10000; //right = 10000
        int ear = (leftRightPan == 10000) ? 0 : 1;

        int freqIndex = (int)TestSeq[currentFreqIndex];


        int testVol = earFreqDBVolAdj[ear, freqIndex, currentTestVolIndex];


        noResponseTimer.Start();
        intervalTimer.Start();

        playTone(testFreqSet[freqIndex], testVol, leftRightPan, tonePlayTime);


        responseDetected = false;
        respondCounter = 0;
        testPerFreqLeft--;
    }

 private void intervalTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        intervalTimer.Stop();   
    }
```

I would like to have an interval of 2 seconds between the previous tone and next tone play. Any idea how this could this be done? Many thanks.

Comment: do you want it to play after every TWO minute ?

Comment: after every 2 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you only need to call DoHearingTest() from your handler function and that should do the trick

Comment: That cannot work as i have another method that determines test sequence. Hence, if i call the method DoHearingTest(), it would have to be DoHearingTest(testseq). Would you like to see the codes or you are able to understand? Sorry for the bad explantion

Comment: Who calls DoHearingTest() ? Is there a way to get the testseq from the  intervalTimer_Elapsed handler function? You could also passing parameters to your handler as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215845/c-sharp-passing-extra-parameters-to-an-event-handler

Comment: Thanks but i have another timer elapsed handler which calls the doHearingTest().

Comment: I think you should add that handler code as well if you want us to get the full picture

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link-
Example sets up an event handler for the Timer.Elapsed event, creates a timer, uses the Interval property to set the timer interval, and starts the timer. The event handler displays the SignalTime property each time it is raised.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I have already tried based on the example but it still cant seem to work. Thanks a lot though

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows.Form.Timer instead What you are using.
like;

```
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        t.Interval = 2000; // time to occuer the tick event
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick); // create event
```

In you Tick Event after every Two minute Write you code for sound;

```
    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.stop();
        doHearingTest(TestSeq); // this is your code to run at every two minute
        t.start();
    }
```

Please do the other changes as needed..!!

Comment: I think you might have read the question wrongly. Firstly, i need the to have a pause of 2 seconds after every tone is played. This is why there are the timers. Secondly, my code wont be running for just 2 minutes. Thirdly, i cannot just call the method doHearingTest(TestSeq) as the test seq is decided from another method. Thanks though.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

which smakes the current thread sleep

Comment: Do i add it at the event handler?